# Electric charges type-postive and negative.positive in protons and negative in electrons.elrctric means electrons negative so why do we includeproton

Tags: electrons, protons

Electric charges are of two types - positive and negative charges.electrons are negatively charged and protons are positively charged. If the term electric means electrons and electric charge means negative charge why do we include protons?  How can a charge be positive? Please correct me if I'm wrong . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around. The term "electricity" was used way before the electron was discovered. It's not electricity who is named after electron but the electron was named so, as it was the first elementary particle discovered and one of it's properties is that interacts with electric fields. Before the electron was discovered, people knew already that there is positive and negative "electricity". So, the term "electric" does not mean specifically "electron" and it includes both positive and negative charge. It was used for a long time before electrons were known to exist, for both positive and negative electricity.

Answer (score 0):

Because the words positive and negative are just that - only words. They do not mean anything. They could just as easily be labeled up and down, or A and B, or hot and cold, or East and West... when Ben Franklin named them he just picked Negative and Positive to have two words that were different.

There really isn't any such thing as "negative" electricity or "negative" particles. In fact many scientists believe that old Ben made a mistake in assigning the word "negative" to the electron and "positive" to protons, as almost 100% of the *visible* effects of electromagnatism come from the flow or proximity, of electrons, so they really should have been labeled as the "positive" one of the pair.
[image]

The only thing that matters is that like charges repel one another, and different charges attract one another.

Comment: The whole "charge of the electron should be plus thing" is misleading. Electric current isn't just a flow of electrons. Indeed, the electric current in your neurons that allows you to make sense of this comment is a current of positive ions. Metals, where the current is electrons, are a special case. But then there's aluminum...

Comment: Also, this doesn't address the main misconception in the question, which is the idea that the term *electricity* refers only to the behavior of electrons.

Comment: @Charles Bretana What scientists believe that it is a mistake? Any reference?

Comment: The point is that the words positive and negative communicate a misleading impression as to the nature of charge.  And the "positiveness" of a positive ion could also be attributed to the electrons - to the number of electrons in the outer shell being less than the number of protons in the nucleus. The "positiveness" is due to hole or absense of an electron in what would otherwise be a complete, full outer shell.  The electrons are also "flowing".